# refer to interface in package from subdirectory of package

Tags: go

have a package with a sub directory (sub-package) and and cannot use interface defined in package from sub-package.

So,

have package f1
  create sub directory f2

in f1 define an interface:

--- /f1/file1.go ---

```
package f1

type Miner interface {
    Foo()
}

func TheFunction( m Miner) { /* blah */ }
```

in f2 create a struct that should be part of interface in f1:

--- /f1/f2/file2.go ---

```
package f2

type Mine struct {
    i int
}
func (m *Mine) Foo() {/* blah */}
```

In a different file,  I try to use the package and create the Mine struct and pass to a function as the interface Miner:

--- ./test_file.go ---

```
package main

import (
    "f1"
    "f1/f2"
)

m := f2.Mine{}
f1.TheFunction(&m)
```

This gives an error "f2.Mine does not implement interface f1.Miner...  Want f1.Foo() but have f2.Foo()

Hope that makes sense.
 So, how can I create a struct in sub-directory f2 that uses interface from f1?

thanks,

Comment: The code you've posted is not syntactically correct (e.g. assigning a type to the variable `m`).  Can you post a complete example?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely nothing is wrong with your packages or directories: Your `f2.Mine` just doesn't implement `Miner`. Only `f2.*Mine` has a method `Foo()`.

Have a look at http://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers and http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets

Comment: I wrote that wrong, the object is passed as a pointer in my code so should be:  TheFunction(&m). Still I have the same error.

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to a pointer, but because the struct was defined in package f2 so it complains you have f2.Foo() but want f1.Foo(). Why is it I can duct type oi.Reader interface methods to structs but this is complaining because the interface is in a different scope?

Answer (score 0):

After your update to the question, I had a go building your test program.  It wasn't quite valid due to the code outside of a function in `test_file.go`, but wrapping that in a `main` function allowed it to compile and run without error.  Had you actually tried running your simplified test case?

I was able to provoke an error similar to what you list by modifying the program further to rename the `Foo` method to `foo`.  In that case, the error was:

```
./test_file.go:10: cannot use &m (type *f2.Mine) as type f1.Miner in function argument:
    *f2.Mine does not implement f1.Miner (missing f1.foo method)
        have f2.foo()
        want f1.foo()
```

This occurs because `foo` is not an [exported identifier](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers).  Since it is not exported, only types within the `f1` package with a `foo` method will conform to the `f1.Miner` interface.

If this is the error you experienced, you will need to make sure the interface is comprised of exported methods if you want types from other packages to be able to implement it.